# Operator '>' and '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string' C#

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

C# program made in Visual Studio 2015 that asks the user to guess a number from 1-10 that will tell the user if the guess was right, greater than or lesser than the value that must be guessed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rightGuess = "7";

        Console.WriteLine("Guess the right number from 1-10: ");
        string userGuess;
        userGuess = Console.ReadLine();
        {
            if (userGuess == rightGuess)
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed right!");
            else if (userGuess > rightGuess)
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess. Your guess was greater than the right guess.");
            else (userGuess < rightGuess)
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess. Your guess was lesser than the right guess.");
        }
    }
```

The program returns following errors in Visual Studio 2015:
[image: errors]

Have researched about an hour on Google how to solve the errors but none of the solutions fixed the errors.

Comment: You're trying to compare strings. First, convert the user input to an integer using something like `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare integers rather than strings (to achieve that kind of compare), change this lines to:

```
int rightGuess = 7;

int userGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

and it will work. Of course you can add `int.TryParse` and check if input was actually an int

```
int userGuess;

if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userGuess))
{
    ... do your logic
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a number");
}
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. It fixed the problem. I was not aware of that both need to be int rather than string.

Comment: @Mikex64 glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the right data type to compare

```
int rightGuess = 7;
Console.WriteLine("Guess the right number from 1-10: ");
int userGuess;
userGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
{
    if (userGuess == rightGuess)
        Console.WriteLine("You guessed right!");
    else if (userGuess > rightGuess)
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess. Your guess was greater than the right guess.");
    else (userGuess < rightGuess)
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess. Your guess was lesser than the right guess.");
}
```

Think like this when you say "Mohit" is greater than "Mikex64" does it make any sense. **No**

But 2 is greater than 1 make sense. thus we can write it like 2 > 1 but cannot write "Mohit" > "Mikex64" thus you are getting this error message.

Edit: edited the "greater than" and "lesser than" operands from code to be accurate as I first wrote them wrong way.

Comment: now I understand the difference between string and int. I did not realize that string is rather text than digits while int is only digits. Though "Mohit" > "Mikex64" would work in this case as you are greater than me in Programming ;) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for such a Generous and Kind Comment :) "Mohit" == "Mikex64"

Answer (score 0):

either convert the string to numeric values using int.Parse/TryParse or use String.CompareTo().

Comment: string.Compare doesn't work in this case: "17" is < "7" e.g.